# Create a JMeter Test to Trigger a SSE Connection Multiple Times

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmx, server-sent-events

I am trying to create a JMeter test to trigger an SSE connection ~5000 times in order to test the total number of SSE connections that can be handled on one instance of my BFF. Is this something someone has done before?

I have only ever used JMeter for HTTP requests, so I am unsure how to use JMeter to trigger multiple SSE connections

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box JMeter doesn't support SSE (at least as of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6)) so you will need to use a library which implements SSE, for example [okhttp-eventsource](https://github.com/launchdarkly/okhttp-eventsource)

The library API can be called either from [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or you can [write your own JMeter plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html)

Example implementation with code snippets: [How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-sse)

Alternatively you can consider another load testing tool which supports SSE, i.e. [Gatling](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/sse/) does